# Proving the product of a numeric sequence and a sequence of random variables converges

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

> Suppose that the sequence of random variables $\{X_{n}\}$ converges to
>   a random variable $X$ in distribution, and a numeric sequence $a_n$
>   converges to $1$. Prove that $a_nX_n$ converges to $X$ in
>   distribution.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. I recently learned about Weak Convergence, but that seems to be no help here. For example, I am aware of Prokhorov's Theorem, but that seems to be useless here. So I am instead trying to use different inequalities, like Markov's, Chebyshev, etc. I'm studying for my exam and will greatly appreciate your help in solving the problem.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Such a statement seems almost obvious, E.g. if we replace "random variables" with "complex numbers", the convergence is immediate. So, have you tried just writing it out?

Comment: I as going to answer this question, but if it is a duplicate then I will defer to your wisdom, @saz.